# ERROR Invalid NUMERIC - Informatica Cloud

Tags: salesforce, cloud, informatica

i'm trying to extract data from a source in salesforce but i'm having 'INVALID NUMERIC' error. Analyzing the log, i realized that error is being caused by a decimal number with many decimal digits, something like 40 decimal digits. Looking in the salesforce configuration, that fiel is defined with 2 decimal digits. Someone knows why the informatica cloud can't read this field and why is trying get this value with many decimal digits even being right in salesforce?

i'm getting the data directly from the salesforce,
through a connection. The data type in Informatica is decimal, even in source and target. The number in salesforce appears as 32.18 and is defined as decimal too, but when i try to get the data with informatica, this is the error: [ERROR] The [LOAD] job failed with the error - [Invalid NUMERIC value: 32.17999999999999971578290569595992565155029296875 Field: COLUMN; Value: 32.17999999999999971578290569595992565155029296875].

Comment: Are you pulling this data directly from Salesforce or is it going via a file? What is the column definition in the Informatica source? Are the extra digits zeros or oes it look like an actual value? Please add the relevant section of the log file to your question

Comment: @nickw, i'm gettin the data directly from the salesforce, 
through a connection. The data type in Informatica is decimal, even in source and target. The number in salesforce appears as 32.18, but when i try to get the data with informatica, this is the error: [ERROR] The [LOAD] job failed with the error - [Invalid NUMERIC value: 32.17999999999999971578290569595992565155029296875 Field: COLUMN; Value: 32.17999999999999971578290569595992565155029296875].

Comment: Please provide the precision and scale of the decimal datatypes in both Salesforce and Informatica. From the example you’ve given, it is obvious that while Salesforce might only be displaying 2 decimal places it is holding the data at a much higher precision or possibly as a FLOAT datatype - and you will need to use this higher precision in Informatica (or round/truncate the value)

Comment: But is how I sad, man, in the both systems the data type was defined equal. Informatica cloud is defined as a decimal with 2 decimal digits but is trying to pull this data with many decimal digits, like 32.17999999999999971578290569595992565155029296875. I've already tried to change data type, change precision and scale but nothing work.

Comment: This link suggests that Salesforce can hold data at a much higher precision than the field definitions allow for. If this is the case then you would need to define the Informatica column with the max precision Salesforce allows (24) or (if possible) override the extract process to truncate this field and any other like it. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&mode=1&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&id=000336833&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1

Comment: @NickW, i think that is one possibility to solve the problem. I implemented a expression to round the number in informatica cloud. Let's see if it will work. Thank you very much!

Comment: The data shown above is not NUMERIC. This is FLOAT. Please change the data type to Float and you should be fine!